# .net using xml for mapping csv to class

Tags: c#, xml, csv, mapping

I have a Task where I have to read an csv file and write the content into a c# List.
Since the csv file can change its layout (caption/order) in the future I want to use a configuration file for mapping the attributes.

Now I am wondering if there is an example out there so I don't have to reinvent the weel :D

My datasource looks like this (tab stop seperated)

```
Customer No.    Customer Name    Created       Discount
10215           John Doe         2010-08-25    5050.23
```

And my class like this:

```
Class Customer
{
    string CustomerNo {get;set;}
    string CustomerName {get;set;}
    DateTime CreatedOn {get;set;}
    decimal Discount {get;set;}
}
```

Now I want to have an external xml file with the definition so I can modify it at runtime without recompiling the code.

```
<customermapping mapstoclass="my.namespace.Customer">
    <attribute csvcaption="Customer No." mapstoproperty="CustomerNo"
               typeof="System.String" required="true">
    <attribute csvcaption="Customer Name" mapstoproperty="CustomerName"
               typeof="System.String" required="true"> 
    <attribute csvcaption="Created" mapstoproperty="CreatedOn"
               typeof="System.DateTime" required="false">
    <attribute csvcaption="Discount" mapstoproperty="Discount"
               typeof="System.Decimal" required="false">
</customermapping>
```

At the end of the Day I want to do the following:
(I already can read all the values from the csv file (the first line is the caption and is in a seperate array)

```
List<Customer> customers =
    CreateCustomerList(string[] csvCaptions, string[] csvLines, 
                       "c:\customermapping.xml");
```

Shouldn't be to complicated but as I said, if someone already did something similar, any examples are welcome.

Comment: Hello, ever got a proper working solution ... I'm experiencing same problem now... thanks

Comment: @jalchr: No, but for my last projects I used CsvHelper (from nuget) which is awesome. It should be possible to create a configuration in code and serialize it to xml.

Comment: actually I'm interested in the other way around. I need to have configuration defined in xml and applied to incoming files against a standard class model. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to reinvent the xsd schema. If you can change the format use the xml and define that rules in the xml.

If you can't change the format or your data is too large to fit nicely in to xml I guess you are on your own. CSV isn't rather an adhoc format I don't think any body cared enough to create a schema validation for it.

Comment: I don't want to reinvent xsd. I want to `use` xml to define mappings between my data and my classes. Like nhibernate maps database tables to class properties.
As I said, shouldn't be too complicated to implement but maybe there is a generic solution out there.

Comment: @SchlaWiener I meant that you would like to creating something like xsd for csv. I just suggested to use xml instead of csv and use xsd to define your mapping. Then you can use xsd.exe to map create mapping between your objects and the xml files.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into using LINQ for this.  There is an articles on LINQ to TEXT here:

- [Tutorial Reading A Text File Using LINQ](http://www.thereforesystems.com/tutorial-reading-a-text-file-using-linq/)
- [LINQ to TEXT and LINQ to CSV](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/09/30/linq-to-text-and-linq-to-csv.aspx)

**Update:** I've re-read your question and I'm no longer sure that using LINQ will really help solve your problem, however I'm leaving the answer here just in case it helps.

If you can at all help it I would put the logic about what columns map onto what properties in code rather than in xml files.